# Money bills cannot be sent back by president in India's parliamentary system

Tags: india, parliament

In Indian parliament, the president cannot send the money bills back for reconsideration of the houses but he can withhold them permanently (pocket veto).
What is the logic behind this rule? What is the loss if he can send the bill back for reconsideration to the houses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money_bill#India) (points 10 and 11) states that money bills in India are presented to the Lok Sabha (lower house of the Indian Parliament) with the permission of the President and therefore there is no need for someone to send a bill back to Parliament after they have already agreed to it (because the President would not allow the bill to be presented if they disagreed with it).